# Error while adding Conv1D layer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying  to train on a data containing sequences of 43 records of 3-dimensional vectors. While trying to add this Conv1D layer here:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(input_shape=(43, 3),
                 filters=16,
                 kernel_size=4,
                 padding='same'))  # This is line 24 of bcl_model_builder.py
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
```

I am getting the following error. And I got no clue what went wrong here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shx/programs/pycharm-community-2017.1.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1585, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/shx/programs/pycharm-community-2017.1.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1015, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/shx/programs/pycharm-community-2017.1.3/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/shx/PycharmProjects/FBS/bcl/bcl_train_model.py", line 34, in <module>
    model = mb.build_model()
  File "/home/shx/PycharmProjects/FBS/bcl/bcl_model_builder.py", line 24, in build_model
    padding='same'))
  File "/home/shx/pyenvs/finainpy_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 442, in add
    layer(x)
  File "/home/shx/pyenvs/finainpy_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 602, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shx/pyenvs/finainpy_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 156, in call
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate[0])
  File "/home/shx/pyenvs/finainpy_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3124, in conv1d
    data_format=tf_data_format)
  File "/home/shx/pyenvs/finainpy_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 672, in convolution
    op=op)
  File "/home/shx/pyenvs/finainpy_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 338, in with_space_to_batch
    return op(input, num_spatial_dims, padding)
  File "/home/shx/pyenvs/finainpy_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 664, in op
    name=name)
  File "/home/shx/pyenvs/finainpy_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 116, in _non_atrous_convolution
    name=scope)
  File "/home/shx/pyenvs/finainpy_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 2013, in conv1d
    data_format=data_format)
  File "/home/shx/pyenvs/finainpy_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 397, in conv2d
    data_format=data_format, name=name)
  File "/home/shx/pyenvs/finainpy_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 589, in apply_op
    param_name=input_name)
  File "/home/shx/pyenvs/finainpy_env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 60, in _SatisfiesTypeConstraint
    ", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType float64 not in list of allowed values: float16, float32
```

Comment: Did you try reading the error ? It is pretty explicit what the problem is here. Make sure your code is using float tensors everywhere and not double tensors.

Comment: But this module bcl_model_builder only creates the model and stacks up the layers. I am still unable to get where is a tensor being used already, because I have not started training on data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving so much thought on float64 in the error log, I realized that  keras itself was configured that way in my machine

```
{
    "floatx": "float64",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "tensorflow",
    "image_data_format": "channels_last"
}
```

I just  had to update the property floatx to float32.